# How to pass around pointer in struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, reference

I think I am not properly dereferencing the thing in my struct.  It compiles but I get a wrong value.  What am I doing wrong?

```
struct MyStruct {
  Thing* thing;
}

void a_library_function(const Thing& thing);

void my_function(const MyStruct& my_struct) {
  if (my_struct.thing != NULL) {
    a_library_function(*(my_struct.thing));
  }
}

MyStruct my_struct;
my_struct.thing = &a_thing;
my_function(my_struct);
```

Comment: Worked for me, after I filled in the missing pieces.  Maybe your missing pieces have a bug in them?  A [mcve] would help.

Comment: what life scope of `a_thing`?

Comment: I suspect triclosan has nailed it.  Here's an example of a relatively common error.  Let's say you actually call a function to initialize your MyStruct.  In that function, you create a Thing on the stack and save a pointer in the struct.  When that function returns, the Thing no longer exists -- you have a pointer to garbage.  Very easy to do.

Comment: That's definitely the problem.  Thank you.